# What is the correct method to calculate contextualized embeddings using Roberta?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to calculate contextualized embeddings using the `RobertaModel`. However, I'm not sure about the correct approach, I have tried two methods, the first method is as follows:

```
from transformers import RobertaModel, RobertaTokenizer
import torch

model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

captions = ["example caption", "colorful bird"]

tokenized_captions = tokenizer(captions, return_tensors='pt', padding=True)

input_ids = tokenized_captions['input_ids']
attention_mask = tokenized_captions['attention_mask']

output = model(input_ids, attention_mask)
contextualized_embedding = output.last_hidden_state

print(contextualized_embedding)
```

The output for the first method:

```
tensor([[[-0.0524,  0.0920, -0.0036,  ..., -0.0810, -0.0577, -0.0343],
         [ 0.0383, -0.1632,  0.1182,  ..., -0.3812, -0.1962, -0.0302],
         [-0.0504,  0.0927, -0.0312,  ..., -0.1355, -0.0663, -0.0727],
         ...,
         [-0.0478, -0.1817,  0.1025,  ..., -0.1187, -0.1293, -0.0288],
         [-0.0478, -0.1817,  0.1025,  ..., -0.1187, -0.1293, -0.0288],
         [-0.0478, -0.1817,  0.1025,  ..., -0.1187, -0.1293, -0.0288]],
```

The output includes non-zero weights for padding tokens. For the second method, the code is essentially the same, with the differences are the lines for `output` and `contextualized_embedding`:

```
output = model(input_ids)
contextualized_embedding = output.last_hidden_state * attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).float()
```

The output for the second method:

```
tensor([[[-0.0502,  0.0605, -0.0332,  ..., -0.1521, -0.0830, -0.0196],
         [ 0.0178, -0.2104,  0.1093,  ..., -0.5506, -0.2059, -0.0825],
         [-0.0484,  0.0579, -0.0615,  ..., -0.2082, -0.0855, -0.0473],
         ...,
         [ 0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000,  ..., -0.0000, -0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000,  ..., -0.0000, -0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000,  ..., -0.0000, -0.0000,  0.0000]],
```

In this case, the output shows zeros for padding tokens, I'm not sure about the correct method, can anyone help me clarify this ?

Comment: The last three vectors represent padding tokens. It depends on what you want to do with the contextualized embeddings to answer your question. To get the token embeddings, it doesn't matter (since the padding tokens are not relevant).

Comment: Are contextualized embeddings and token embeddings the same thing? I agree _padding tokens are not relevant_. That's why I'm asking whether I should use the first or the second method to handle these tokens, as their outputs are different. Additionally, you need to forward `attention_mask` to ignore these padding tokens, thanks

Comment: Both terms are not specific enough to say without context that they refer to the same thing. Token embeddings can be contextualized or not contextualized. 

I also do not understand your use case. When you say that you will ignore the padding tokens, it doesn't matter what values their vectors have.

Comment: I was talking about the contextualized token embeddings from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605657/how-to-understand-contextualized-embeddings-in-transformer/77611233#77611233), _doesn't matter what values their vectors have_, I read somewhere that multiplying the output from `RobertaModel` by the `attention_mask` to assign a weight of zero to padding tokens when calculating contextualized token embeddings. This is what the second method is about

Comment: When reading the [HuggingFace documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/roberta#transformers.RobertaModel.forward.attention_mask), they already have a parameter for this purpose. That's why I'm not sure about the correct approach

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed another difference, the first approach passes `input_ids` and `attention_mask`, while the second method passes only `input_ids`. The second method is completely wrong, you always want `model(input_ids, attention_mask)`. Regarding multiplying the output with the `attention_mask`, I think you mix it up with sentence embeddings. For them it matters, but not for token_embeddings.